# ASP.NET MVC] Route match but controller never called. -> 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Hi everyone I have a problem with MVC3 routing and areas:

My route matches but the controller is never called, instead i get a 404 error.

I have set an MVC3 solution with 2 project:

- One is the main MVC Project: CityServices
- One for an area: CityServices.Demo

[image: ProjectSetup]

In my area I register the following route:

```
public class TestAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default",
            "Test/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Stuff", action = "ListAll" }
        );
    }
}
```

Content of StuffController.cs:

```
public class StuffController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ListAll()
    {
        List<Stuff> lstStuff = new List<Stuff>
                                   {
                                       new Stuff()
                                           {
                                               Id = 0,
                                               Name = "HEeey",
                                               Value = 10.456f
                                           },
                                       new Stuff()
                                           {
                                               Id = 1,
                                               Name = "Beeee",
                                               Value = 456789.47879999f
                                           },
                                       new Stuff()
                                           {
                                               Id = 2,
                                               Name = "HooAAaoo",
                                               Value = 0f
                                           }
                                   };

        return Json(lstStuff);
    }
}
```

I register area in the main project:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        //RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

My route is matched: http://host/Test
But i always get a 404 error.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
- Jeremy

Edit: Here is a proof that the route matches:

[image]

**Found Solution**

So to sum it up.
**My AreaRegistration inherited class was not in the same namespace as my controllers.**
Since i did not have any views (it's just a restful websvc) i did not have to use MvcContribs which seems to be useful when you have views&controllers in a differents project than the main site.

Hope this helps if you arrive on this question ;)

Comment: How have you checked that your route is really matched by the request?

Comment: I've added a screenshot where you can see that the route is matched. (Using Haack's route debugger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your area in another project which won't work per default unless you are using MvcContribs portable areas or another custom implementation

Comment: It's strange since route injection works. I'll try to google your advice

Comment: I've tried MvcContribs (http://goo.gl/OmCxZ). It worked following their post. But actually the problem was not about not using a custom impl. It was a namespace issue (which i found out while reading the MvcContribs post). It seems that MvcContribs custom impl is useful when you are using views, which i don't use in this project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the allow get for json:

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Comment: I did it with the area in the same project as my application. You will need the combination of these two answers.